# What can be the reason for issue with the POST request for this MERN stack application backend API?

Tags: rest, express, http, postman, backend

I'm creating a simple social media application.

I'm getting an error message with **400** status code in **response** on sending `POST` **request** with **name,email and password** in the body of the request in the **JSON** format.

I'm using **POSTMAN** tool to test the **backend API.**

Below is the response I'm getting with **400** status code, on sending `POST` **request** to `http://localhost:3000/api/users/`.

**error message as response**.

```js
{
    "error": "Password is required !"
}
```

**express.js file**

```js
import express from "express";
import path from "path";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import compress from "compression";
import cors from "helmet";
import helmet from "cors";
import Template from "./../template";
import userRoutes from "./routes/user.routes";
import authRoutes from "./routes/auth.routes";

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(compress());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());

// app.use('/dist', express.static(path.join(CURRENT_WORKING_DIR, 'dist')));

app.use('/', userRoutes);
app.use('/', authRoutes);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send(Template());
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if (err.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
    res.status(401).json({
      "error": err.name + ": " + err.message
    });
  } else if (err) {
    res.status(400).json({
      "error": err.name + ": " + err.message
    });
    console.log(err);
  }
});

export default app;
```

**user.controller.js i.e., controller**

```js
import User from '../models/user.model';
import extend from 'lodash/extend';
import errorHandler from '../helpers/dbErrorHandler';

// Create user(s).
const create = async (req, res) => {
    const user = new User(req.body);
    try {
        await user.save();
        return res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Successfully signed up.'
        });
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            error: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    }
};

// Loading a user after receiving a users/:userId parameter.
const userById = async (req, res, next, id) => {
    try {
        let user = await User.findById(id);
        if (!user) {
            return res.status('400').json({
                error: "User not found"
            });
        }
        req.profile = user;
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status('400').json({
            error: 'Couldn\'t retrieve the user'
        });
    }
};

// Reading a single user's data.
const read = (req, res) => {
    req.profile.hashed_password = undefined;
    req.profile.salt = undefined;
    return res.json(req.profile);
};

// Listing all the users.
const list = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let users = await User.find().select('name email updated created');
        res.json(users);
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            error: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    }
};

// Update a single user's data.
const update = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let user = req.profile;
        user = extend(user, req.body);
        user.updated = Date.now();
        await user.save();
        user.hashed_password = undefined;
        user.salt = undefined;
        res.json(user);
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            error: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    }
};

// Delte a user.
const remove = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let user = req.profile;
        let deleteUser = await User.remove();
        deleteUser.hashed_password = undefined;
        deleteUser.salt = undefined;
        res.json(deleteUser);
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            error: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    }
};

export default {
    create,
    userById,
    read,
    list,
    remove,
    update
};
```

**user.model.js i.e., model**

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: "Name is required",
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    unique: "Email already exists",
    match: [/.+\@.+\..+/, "Please fill a valid email address"],
    required: "Email address is required !",
  },
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  updated: Date,
  hashed_password: {
    type: String,
    required: "Password is required !",
  },
  salt: String,
});

/**
 * The password string that's provided by the user is not stored directly in the user
 * document. Instead, it is handled as a virtual field.
 */
UserSchema.virtual("password")
  .set(function (password) {
    this._password = password;
    this.salt = this.makeSalt();
    this.hashed_password = this.encryptPassword(password);
  })
  .get(function () {
    return this._password;
  });

/**
 * The encryption logic and salt generation logic, which are used to generate the
 * hashed_password and salt values representing the password value, are defined as
 * UserSchema methods.
 */
UserSchema.methods = {
  authenticate: function (plainText) {
    return this.authenticate(plainText) === this.hashed_password;
  },
  encryptPassword: function (password) {
    if (!password) return "";
    try {
      return crypto
        .createHmac("sha1", this.salt)
        .update(password)
        .digest("hex");
    } catch (err) {
      return "";
    }
  },
  makeSalt: function () {
    return Math.round(new Date().valueOf() * Math.random()) + "";
  },
};

/**
 * To add validation constraints to the actual password string that's selected by the end
 * user, we need to add custom validation logic and associate it with the hashed_password
 * field in the schema.
 */
UserSchema.path("hashed_password").validate(function (v) {
  if (this._password && this._password.length < 8) {
    this.invalidate("password", "Password must be atleast 8 characters.");
  }
  if (this.isNew && !this._password) {
    this.invalidate("password", "Password is required.");
  }
}, null);

export default mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Comment: seems like `hashed_password` is missing in the `POST` request

Comment: @Darkripper Would you mind elaborating it ?

Comment: In your schema, 

hashed_password: {
    type: String,
    required: "Password is required !",
  },

So it is most likely your `hashed_password` is missing when you're trying to create a `document`, hence the `error`.

So try to look along the flow of data and make sure `hashed_password` is there when you try to do `const user = new User(req.body);`